# Quarkus Panache Not Working with persistence.xml after 1.8

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have an existing Quarkus application that uses the Hibernate Panache extension. It works great with 1.7.5.Final. I have a persistence.xml file in:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

What do I have to do to keep this setup working with Quarkus 1.8.x or 1.9?

Running the same application in Quarkus when updating past 1.7 gives me this error:

```
[org.hib.hql.int.QuerySplitter] (executor-thread-1) HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: FROM ...
```

I saw the support for multiple persistence units in 1.8, I'm assuming that has something to do with it. I've gone through the setup guides but nothing is working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.